# Submanifolds of $4$-manifolds and their intersections

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Suppose we have two (oriented) submanifolds $A,B$ of an oriented $4$-dimensional manifold $M$, that intersect transversally. Looking at the standard references for $4$-manifolds, I couldn't find a discussion regarding the *realization* of their intersection number:

Is it true that two transverse $2$-dimensional, oriented submanifolds $A,B$ of $M$ can be isotoped such that they realize the intersection number predicted by the intersection form of $M$ (with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients)? If not, are there counterexamples or certain conditions that ensure that such an isotopy is possible?

In particular, do there exist smooth $2$-dim submanifolds with $0$ intersection number but that **cannot** be made disjoint?

It seems to me that this question is very related to canceling pairs of intersection points with opposite signs. Literature on this subject would also be greatly appreciated!

I am mainly interested where everything is understood in the smooth category.

Comment: For literature (not 4 dim case) look at Milnor's h cobordism theorem book.

Comment: You generally can't realize the algebraic intersection number by the actual count of the intersection points.  This stems from the failure of the Whitney trick -- this is the tool used in high dimensions to ensure you can realize algebraic intersection number.  There is a large literature on this topic, look for papers by Freedman, Krushkal, Schneiderman, etc.

Comment: If you go one co-dimension lower, i.e. 3-manifolds in 4-manifolds, the situation is similarly complicated.

Comment: "In particular, do there exist smooth 2-dim submanifolds with 0 intersection number but that cannot be made disjoint?"

Yes. That is example 6.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5534.pdf.

Comment: @NickL: That paper (and the papers it cites) surely contains an answer. But Example 6.2 seems to be about the impossibility of pulling apart 3 spheres with pairwise zero intersections. They also remark (in the Introduction) that 2 spheres with zero intersection number can always be pulled apart.

Comment: I want to mention that these papers, although showing that two spheres **can** be pulled apart in a simply connected $4$-manifold, they work with *immersions*, since they transfer the mutual intersections of the two spheres to self intersections of one of the two spheres. So, if I understand correctly, even when we start with embedded spheres, to use the Whitney trick ( as in  arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5534.pdf), we will end up with disjoint **immersed** spheres.